# Fill NaN values of a single column where matching values are found in another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have two data frames: 'df' and 'dfcup'.
'df' has NaN values in some rows for the variable "Cup"

[image: df]

My second data frame 'dfcup' is a .groupby() and .sort() call on the 'df' to produce a 'count' of the number of times a "Height","Weight" and "Cup" combination appear:

```
dfcup = df.groupby(['Height','Weight','Cup']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

[image: dfcup]

The goal is to replace NaN values in the df['Cup'] column with the first matching dfcup['Cup'] based on "Height" and "Weight".

For example, for a given "Height" and "Weight" of "65.0" and "130.0", replace NaN values in df['Cup'] with "B" (as found in dfcup['Cup']

Is this possible with a "for" loop, or something similar?

Comment: for answer, need minimal and reproducible code not image https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This problem is not difficult and does not require loop. Please make only copyable example(`df`).

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

i make minimal and reproducible example, becuz you dont provide minimal and reproducible code. This example is different from yours so use only logic. you don need make `df_cup` to solve it.

```
data = {'c1': {0: 64, 1: 63, 2: 64, 3: 63, 4: 63, 5: 64, 6: 63, 7: 64},
        'c2': {0: 'A', 1: 'D', 2: 'B', 3: None, 4: 'C', 5: None, 6: 'C', 7: 'B'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    c1  c2
0   64  A
1   63  D
2   64  B
3   63  None
4   63  C
5   64  None
6   63  C
7   64  B
```

when `c1` is 64, B is most in `c2`, when `c1` is 63, C is most in `c2`

---

**Code**

```
df.assign(c2=df.groupby('c1')['c2'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0])))
```

output:

```
    c1  c2
0   64  A
1   63  D
2   64  B
3   63  C <-- None of 63 filled by C (most of 63)
4   63  C
5   64  B <-- None of 64 filled by B (most of 64)
6   63  C
7   64  B
```

Use this logic to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Does the .groupby() method take two arguments? It's important to first look at "Height", then "Weight" to perform a fillna(mode) of "Cup".